# How to scrape HTML data-endpoints with Beautiful Soup (modal containers)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently trying to scrape data from baseball reference and all is going well except I've hit a problem with trying to scrape data within a modal container/data-endpoint. Now, I actually don't know HTML, though I'm familiar enough to get by with scraping easily enough - which is why I'm not sure if I should be classifying what I'm trying to enter as a data-endpoint or a modal-container. Hopefully it will be made clear below:

If you go to https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/gl.fcgi?id=torregl01&t=b&year=2019 , an example page I'm trying to scrape from, and view the column labeled "PA", you'll see clicking on the value loads a pop-up window. I'm trying to scrape info from that window, which is what is causing issues for me - I simply don't know how to scrape information that isn't directly on the webpage.

Below is the html I've found for the container through "Inspect":
[image: HTML]

I also found that the "PA" cell in each row has a data-endpoint listed in its properties shown below:
[image: Cell data-endpoint]

I'm unsure how to access the information in the pop-up window and would prefer to do it using Beautiful Soup if possible. If someone could at least point me in the right direction as to scraping info off these types of pop-up windows that would be super helpful.

A huge thank you to anyone kind enough to help me - it will be very much appreciated!

Comment: What are you using to fetch the page content initially?  Are you using `requests`?

Comment: Yes. page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

Comment: It sounds like the page has javascript that it uses to dynamically create pop-up windows and such, and requests can't handle that.  You'll have to use something like Selenium that behaves like an actual browser.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: Actually, that data-endpoint appended to the base url gives a new webpage with the desired information. I'll try to load that webpage as a separate "soup"

Answer (score 1):

My solution uses requests and beautiful soup alone (and pandas to display solution). Edit: The piece of code before had careless mistakes in them. The following should take any player's url and get all the popups. Note, the program starts to slow down considerably after many requests.

## Code

```py
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

players_list = [
    'https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/gl.fcgi?id=torregl01&t=b&year=2019',
    'https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/gl.fcgi?id=troutmi01&t=b&year=2019',
    'https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/gl.fcgi?id=lindofr01&t=b&year=2019'
]

all_dfs = {}
for player in players_list:
    r = requests.get(player)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    dates = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'data-stat': 'date_game'})

    player_id = re.search(r'id=(\w+)', player).group(1)
    params = {
        'html': '1',
        'date_out': '1',
        't': 'b'
    }
    popup_url = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/be.cgi'
    temp_df_holder = []
    for date in dates:
        if date.get('csk'):
            param_date = re.search(r'\.(\w+)', date['csk']).group(1)
            params['game-id'] = param_date + '-' + player_id
            popup = requests.get(popup_url, params=params)
            print(popup.url)
            df = pd.read_html(popup.text)
            temp_df_holder.append(df)
    all_dfs[player_id] = temp_df_holder
    print(f'Player {player_id} done')

print(all_dfs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply!
The only issue with this solution is that I am also trying to get information from the row that the "PA" cell is in (which I've done already) and that your pop up window url was hardcoded -- and I will need to do this for many players. Still helped with figuring out the structure of the HTML, so thank you

Comment: The code I provided grabs the pop up window for every row in your url. If you look inside the for loop, you can see I’m adding a parameter specific to each row.

Comment: Correct. But, for example, you're also adding "-torregl01" which is player specific

Comment: torregl01 is in the url of the website with the table as a parameter. This could probably be automated to grab the player id and use it.